# How can I publish exactly once when the node is run?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish a single /initialpose message when a node is run. How can I make sure it's only published once?

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseWithCovarianceStamped
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from numpy import matrix

class PoseChange:
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = PoseWithCovarianceStamped()
        rospy.init_node("pose_change", anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber('/pose', Pose, self.callback)
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/initialpose', PoseWithCovarianceStamped, queue_size=3)

    def callback(self, data):
        self.msg.header = Header()
        self.msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        self.msg.header.frame_id = "map"
        self.msg.pose.pose = data
        self.msg.pose.covariance = matrix([[0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                                           [0, 0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0.09, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25]])

    def run(self):
        self.pub.publish(self.msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        m = PoseChange()
        m.run()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        raise e
```

However, this never publishes when run. The /pose topic it's listening to is continuously publishing at 50 Hz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267199/how-can-i-publish-exactly-once-when-the-node-is-run?/) by [j1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/30696/j1337/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @j1337,

ROS takes some time to notify the publishers and subscribers of the topics. So, you have two options:

1 - Sleep some seconds before publish the first message. In the "main" part of your code could be done like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:

        from time import sleep
        print 'Sleeping 10 seconds to publish'
        sleep(10)
        print 'Sleep finished.'

        m = PoseChange()
        m.run()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        raise e
```

2 - Make sure that there are subscribers (using [get_num_connections](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections)) when you starts publishing. In the "main" part of your code it would be like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        m = PoseChange()
        rate = rospy.Rate(10)  # 10hz
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            connections = m.pub.get_num_connections()
            rospy.loginfo('Connections: %d', connections)
            if connections > 0:
                m.run()
                rospy.loginfo('Published')
                break
            rate.sleep()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException, e:
        raise e
```

If you still have doubts, I made a video (https://youtu.be/BGV6DI_PItA) that shows how to solve exactly this question by checking the subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [j1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/30696/j1337/) on 2017-07-24**:
Thank you. This was extremely helpful.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-09**:
Why not explain exactly how to solve this question here? The problem with linking to a video for more steps is that now part of the answer is external and this answer is not self-contained. What if the video gets taken down?

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-09**:
Ok, now the answer is self contained, @jayess.

Thanks for the advice.

**Comment by [AlessandroSaviolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/52672/alessandrosaviolo/) on 2020-03-19**:
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it's a known problem. The thing is that when you create a publisher, it's not connect yet to ROS master server.
That's why you are not able to publish the message. You can try to "sleep" for a while, like 1~5 seconds, and the publisher will be connected.

If you need to publish something just once, I'd recommend you to use a **ROS service**.

You can check other related questions:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/32952/with-rospy-messages-dont-seem-to-be-recieved-if-published-soon-after-creating-the-publisher/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/9665/test-for-when-a-rospy-publisher-become-available/?answer=14125#post-id-14125

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is related to this similar question : "[How do I publish exactly one message](http://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/)?"

The problem there was that the message was being published before the publisher or it's subscriber had time to setup all the way, the solution was to wait for a subscriber to subscribe before publishing (in rospy that would use [get_num_connections](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections).)

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2